# Generalized method where method parameter accepts one model and returns different model

Tags: c#

I am trying to write generalized code in which a Method accepts a model as a parameter and return the different model based on the parameter.

Call to method.

```
 UserModelApi model = (UserModelApi) GetModels(dto);
```

Method Definition:

```
    private T GetModels<T>(T _dto)
    {
        T t = default(T);
        if (_dto.GetType() == typeof(UserDTO))
        {
            UserDTO dto = (UserDTO)(object)_dto;
            UserModelApi model = new UserModelApi()
            {
               ........
            };
            return (T)(object)model;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

But this is not working as `UserModelApi model = (UserModelApi)GetModels(dto);` excepts a model (UserModelApi) but its returning UserDTO model.

Question is how do I generalize the method definition where it accepts one model as parameter but returns different model?

Comment: Sounds like a job for AutoMapper

Comment: For starters, if you want the passed in parameter type and the return type to be different types, you ought to be using separate type parameters!

Comment: Look up AutoMapper, looks like what you’re after.

Comment: ya true Damien_The_Unbeliever but there are too many models so thought of giving try

Comment: You could also try using automapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For returning an instance of some other type we'd need another generic type parameter. Let's call it `TResult`. For mapping things we can create a Mapper or use existing lib called `AutoMapper`:

1. Get Automapper NuGet package
2. Change Method by adding new `TResult` parameter and using the `Automapper` to map things:

   ```
   // 'where class' constraint is required because we'll return null as default value
   private static TResult GetModels<T, TResult>(T dto) where TResult : class
   {
       if (dto != null)
       {
           try
           {
               TResult model = null;

               // here we check if the actual mapping exists in AM configuration
               var map = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<T, TResult>();

               if (map != null)
               {
                   model = Mapper.Map<T, TResult>(dto);
               }
               return model;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              // log other errors here
           }
       }
       return default(TResult);
   }
   ```
3. Before we can start using it we'd need to create a mapping. Something along the lines of:

   ```
       Mapper.Initialize(c =>
       {
           c.CreateMap<UserDTO, UserModelApi>().ConvertUsing(f1 => new UserModelApi()
           {
               // add the mapping here
           });
       });
       Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
   ```

And finally we can use the new method:

```
UserModelApi model = GetModels<UserDTO, UserModelApi>(dto);
```

An example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/80jADT

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method and manually copy values from object to the new object through reflection.

```
public static void CopyTo<T>(this object self, T to)
{
    if (self != null)
    {
        foreach (var pi in to.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            pi.SetValue(to, self.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name)?.GetValue(self, null) ?? null, null);
        }
    }
}
```